# C - Insert Values into Struct

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to insert values into a struct so I can display them again later on.

```
typedef struct {
    char* displayname;
    char* name;
} objectHolder;

void registerObject(char* displayname, char* name) {
    objectHolder->displayname = displayname;
    objectHolder->name = name;

    char buffer[70];
    sprintf(buffer, "%s spawned", displayname);

    menu.drawFeedNotification(buffer, "Object Spawner");
}
```

But this returns me:

```
source/main.cpp:82:17: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘->’ token
     objectHolder->displayname = displayname;
                 ^
source/main.cpp:83:17: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘->’ token
     objectHolder->name = name;
```

I have tried to replace the `->` but that didn't do the job either. I can't find results on Google about how to perform this properly. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have *two* problems.

The first is the syntax, where the "arrow" `->` is used for *pointers* to structures.

The other problem is that `objectHolder` is not an actual structure instance, it's not a variable. It is a *type-name*. An alias of the structure type. You use `objectHolder` to declare and define variables of the structure.

Comment: Thanks for your input. What can be the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

In your program, `objectHolder` denotes a type, not a variable/an object. You cannot apply operator `->` to types, only to a pointer to an object.

If you want to introduce a global variable, then you'd need to write:

```
typedef struct {
    char* displayname;
    char* name;
} objectHolderType;

objectHolderType objectHolderObj;
objectHolderType *objectHolder = &objectHolderObj;
...
```

Comment: I want the things I'm trying to insert into the struct to act like a database, so basically when I run multiple different values through `registerObject`, I want to be able to return them later on somewhere else in a loop.

Comment: Then you will have to create `objectHolder`-objects dynamically, e.g. by `objectHolder *oh = new objectHolder;`

Comment: If I do that, what do I have to change things like `objectHolder->displayname = displayname;` to?

Comment: @J.Doe It seems like what you need to know is too broad for a Stack Overflow answer to effectively cover, since you don't even know what a struct *is* - can I suggest finding a tutorial?

Comment: @immibis As mentioned in the question, I cannot find a tutorial or any sort of information on this. I appreciate you taking time to post a comment but this isn't helping me further a single bit.

Comment: @J.Doe There isn't a tutorial explaining what a struct is?